# Auto-Scroll div horizontally to the very end with overflow-y set to scroll (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, autoscroll

I am using this jQuery script that automatically scrolls a div horizontally **based on the width of the div**. But I need it to scroll to the very end of the div based on the **end of the content** that is inside of the div. The div has an 'overflow-y: scroll' attribute, so I'd like it to **scroll** through all of the content until it reaches the end.

This is the script I'm currently using:

```
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
    var width = $(targetElement).width();
    $(targetElement).animate({ marginLeft: "-="+width},
    {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function ()
        {
            targetElement.animate({ marginLeft: "+="+width },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function ()
                {
                    animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
animatethis($('#q1'), 5000);
```

It does scroll, but it's not scrolling to the very end of the content inside of the div. Here is a jFiddle that shows what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/rKu6Y/535/

How can I get it to auto-scroll horizontally to the END of the content rather than just the width of the div?

I hope this all makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: so you want the last word "END" to hide too at the left when the scroll endds right?

Comment: @EnmanuelDuran  
No, just for it to show the word "END". It doesn't need to go any further than that. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can animate the `scrollLeft` property, using `scrollWidth` and `clientWidth`:

```
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
    var scrollWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollWidth;
    var clientWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).clientWidth;
    $(targetElement).animate({ scrollLeft: scrollWidth - clientWidth },
    {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function () {
            targetElement.animate({ scrollLeft: 0 },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function () {
                    animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
animatethis($('#q1'), 5000);
```

The result can be seen in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKu6Y/540/).