# Automated horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an automatic horizontal scrolling page and have found a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337646/auto-scroll-div-horizontally-to-the-very-end-with-overflow-y-set-to-scroll-jque) which has gone some way to helping.

The only thing is I want the user to be able to interact with the scrollbar, so effectively killing the automation if the scrollbar is grabbed.

```js
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
  var scrollWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollWidth;
  var clientWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).clientWidth;
  $(targetElement).animate({
    scrollLeft: scrollWidth - clientWidth
  }, {
    duration: speed,
    complete: function() {
      targetElement.animate({
        scrollLeft: 0
      }, {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function() {
          animatethis(targetElement, speed);
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
animatethis($('#q1'), 5000);
```

```css
#q1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="q1">((BEGIN)) Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me
  Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me ((END))</div>
```

Also in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKu6Y/540/)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code as,

```js
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
  var scrollWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollWidth;
  var clientWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).clientWidth;
  
  // This code is added
  $(targetElement).click(function() {
    $(targetElement).stop();
  });

  $(targetElement).animate({
    scrollLeft: scrollWidth - clientWidth
  }, {
    duration: speed,
    complete: function() {
      targetElement.animate({
        scrollLeft: 0
      }, {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function() {
          animatethis(targetElement, speed);
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
animatethis($('#q1'), 10000);
```

```css
#q1 {
  padding: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="q1">((BEGIN)) Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me
  Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me ((END))</div>
```

Please check out this link,
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_stop.asp

Comment: Thanks but I wanted it to stop when the scrollbar is clicked or interatced with not the element itself. I'm not sure how to arget the scrollbar of a div? Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, it will stop scrolling div whenever the scrollbar is grabbed and on leaving, scrolling again starts from wherever it stops. See here: https://codepen.io/varunraval/pen/ydBgOG

```
init()
function init() {
  targetElement = $('#q1').get(0);
  MaxScroll = false;
  targetElement.scrollLeft = PreviousScroll  = 0;

  ScrollInterval = setInterval('animatethis()', 5);
}

function animatethis() {
  if (!MaxScroll) {
    targetElement.scrollLeft = PreviousScroll;
    PreviousScroll++;
    MaxScroll = targetElement.scrollLeft >= (targetElement.scrollWidth - targetElement.clientWidth);
  }
  else {
    MaxScroll = (targetElement.scrollLeft == 0)?false:true;
    targetElement.scrollLeft = PreviousScroll;
    PreviousScroll--;
  }
}

$('#q1').mousedown(function() {
  clearInterval(ScrollInterval);
});

$('#q1').mouseup(function() {
  ScrollInterval = setInterval('animatethis()', 5);
});

targetElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  clearInterval(ScrollInterval);
}, false)
     
targetElement.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  ScrollInterval = setInterval('animatethis()', 5);
}, false)
```

Comment: Hi this is great but I've just noticed the auto scrolling doesn't work on a mobile? Anyone think of a reason for this?

Comment: I have updated the code you can check now @MintfreshLindfield